# ただ、５年前の…今と同じくらい、ううん、それ以上の大きな幸せに包まれる

Tags: translation

> ただ、５年前の…今と同じくらい、ううん、それ以上の大きな幸せに包まれる

I would translate it as

> five years ago ... Just as much as now, no, it will be wrapped in big happiness even beyond that

I would like to know if this translation truly conveys the meaning of this sentence. It starts with the past, then the present and the future last? I missed something relevant in my translation?

Comment: did you comeup with this sentence or there is a source to it?

Comment: It comes from a book, I didn't make that sentence. I'm afraid it's not online though. I can give you the context if you feel it's needed though

Comment: Something like this: A man breaks up with his girlfriend to go out with her sister. The man says he's leaving the country with her sister. The girl cries for a long time. After a while the girl calms down and begs him to let her come as well (even if she's not his girlfriend anymore). It could be just like 5 years ago when all of them were just friends (the girls are sisters).

Comment: yes, Context always helps, i'm not as experienced with "time" so I'll let someone else answer, the only thing I feel that could be a bit off is "５年前の" that imo should be "５年前" or "５年前に"

Comment: What I would like to know the most is 1) first of all, to confirm that my translation is accurate and that there are 3 times in this sentence: the past, the present and the situation that would ensue if the man agrees (therefore the future) and 2) when was the girl happiest? Two years ago the girl had told the man that by going out with him she had become the happiest she had ever been. Is the sentence in my question a contradiction? (assuming that there she's saying that the future (where the man is longer her boyfriend) will be even happier if they are all together like 5 years ago.

Comment: I think ５年前の… means ５年前の幸せ and 今と同じくらい means 今と同じくらいの幸せ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was born and living over 40 years in Japan.
Your translation:

`five years ago ... Just as much as now, no, It will be wrapped in big happiness even beyond that`

will be good. Implicitly 5年前の and 今と同じくらい points "幸せ", compares "それ以上の大きな".

Comment: I don't understand a couple of things. [1]それ以上の大きな is future or present? Basically is それ以上の大きな the future is is it the same time as 今と同じくらい (both would be the present in that case).  [2] それ以上の大きな means there will be more happiness than 1) 5年前の 2) 今 3)both of them, so more happiness than ever. [3] Since you're japanese how would you translate the sentence if I hadn't given a translation? (if you rephrase it I might understand it better).

Comment: 5 years ago what I was... or now, I will be happier than ever

Comment: [1] (very near)future
[2]  1) 5年前  and 2) 今 the happiest ever (almost same) 

I will tranlalte as follows:
I am  happy  now as 5 years ago what I was the most ...  I will be surrounded(wrapped) the most happiness than ever.

Comment: Another question, why do you say in your translation " I will be surrounded(wrapped) the most happiness than ever". Does it say more than ever? Because 3 years ago she had said she was the happiest she had ever been. Is that a contradiction? Also, in your translation "I am happy now as 5 years ago what I was the most", does it literally say 5 yers ago "she was the most"? Could you give me a completely literal translation of the whole sentence?

Comment: Your Japanese cite did not describe that  any about 3 yeas ago(3年前). 
On that limited informatin, I think she(he) is as happy as what she(he) was 5 years ago, that was my misunderstand. 

And then, I will correct second sentence "I will be surrounded(wrapped) the happier than then"

Comment: Last time: The quote comes from a book. The 3 years ago part was said 200 pages ago and it could have been said on the spur of the moment so it shouldn't affect your translation. Knowing this, what's your definite translation of the whole sentence? (would you say happier than 5 years ago or happier than ever?).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I think "5 years ago" is the comparison.

Comment: So with your good help, my translation will be: "I am happy now as 5 years ago what I was... I will be surrounded(wrapped) the most happiness than 5 years ago."

Comment: which one is the japanese particle that says "the most"? (intead of more than).